# For dentro de for para comparar se existe valores iguais

Tags: angular, typescript

Preciso fazer um for pra verificar se dentro do meu array this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes possui um sku igual ao outro, tentei algo como:

```
for(let i=0;i<this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes.length;i++){
  for(let j=i+1;j<this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes.length;j++){
    if(this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes[i].sku == this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes[j].sku){
      console.log('possui sku iguais')
    }
  }
}
```

No meu console.log está retornando a mensagem mais de uma vez quando tem sku iguais

Também tentei:

```
for(let i=0;i<this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes.length;i++){
  for(let j=0;j<this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes.length - 1;j++){
    if(this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes[j].sku == this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes[j+1].sku){
      console.log('sku iguasi')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: utilize `===` (3 sinais de iguais) no javascript. Assim ele verifica se os tipos das variaveis também são iguais. O `==` verificar se os valores, tanto `string` ou `number`, são semelhantes.

Comment: Não sei como é o seu array, mas, não é mais simples utilizar um **filter()** que utiliza uma função que verifica se o array contém elementos mais de uma vez?

Comment: E qual seria o resultado esperado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria mais interessante você utilizar o método `filter` ou `map` para percorrer os dois arrays, tenta utilizar dessa forma.

```
this.variacaoForm.filter((value,index) => {
    return value.vairacoes.sku === this.variacaoForm.value.variacoes[index].sku });
```